# Kotlin function syntax

Tags: kotlin

I'm doing the Kotlin Koans tests in order to familiarise myself with Kotlin. In a certain test I have to override the `compareTo` method. In the first case everything work as intended

```
data class MyDate(val year: Int, val month: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int) {

    operator fun compareTo(other: MyDate)= when {
        year != other.year -> year - other.year
        month != other.month -> month - other.month
        else -> dayOfMonth - other.dayOfMonth
    }

}
```

Now in the second case where I'm writing the `compareTo` a little bit differently I get a ton of compilation errors.

```
data class MyDate(val year: Int, val month: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int) {


     operator fun compareTo(other: MyDate){

        when {
            year != other.year -> return year - other.year
            month != other.month -> return month - other.month
            else -> return dayOfMonth - other.dayOfMonth
       }
     }


 }
```

First of all, at the operator keyword, I get an error:

> 'operator' modifier is inapplicable on this function: must return Int

and in the returns I get

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Unit was expected

I cannot understand why these errors occur since the first implementation returns the same `Int`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `=` works as `{ return X }`<sub>This applies only to function definitions</sub>. So this means that in the first example your code is equal to this

```
operator fun compareTo(other: MyDate):Int {
    return when {
        year != other.year -> year - other.year
        month != other.month -> month - other.month
        else -> dayOfMonth - other.dayOfMonth
    }
}
```

But in your 2nd example you don't return the result of the `when`. That results in the compiler being confused because it expected you to return a `Int` but you return `Unit` instead (equivalent of Java's `void`)

So all you need to do is to add an explicit return type (`Int` in this case) to it (`fun X(/*args*/)`**`: Int`** or other applicable type)

Comment: This is a little bit off. When you write `fun someFunction(a: Type) { }` (without the `=`), Kotlin will always infer that the return type is `Unit`. It doesn't matter whether he has `return` before `when`, or inside it.

Comment: To follow up my last comment; the only thing he needs to add is the return type (`: Int`) to his function definition. You do not need to put `return` before `when`, because the else-branch of the when-expression makes it exhaustive.

Comment: @marstran [Just checked and you do need the return](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/dcmc5bt52isgk4rhc2ule8toe0/s67it8ebb3i30m05j3870qqj8h)

Comment: Yes, of course you need `return` _somewhere_. You can have it in each of the branches in the when-expression, like he did in his "second case". That's my point.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, the return type of `compareTo(MyDate)` is [inferred](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-functions) as `Int` because all branch of the `when` expression return an `Int`.

In your second example, the return type of `compareTo(MyDate)` is `Unit`. Since you function has the block body, so the return type must be specified explicitly (unless it's intended for them to return `Unit`). So, `Unit` is expected here for the return type, but the return type inferred from your `when` expression is `Int`. That's why you get the error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Unit was expected

Here is the [official explanation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#explicit-return-types) for explicitly defining the return type of functions with block bodies:

> Functions with block body must always specify return types explicitly, unless it's intended for them to return Unit, [in which case it is optional](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions). Kotlin does not infer return types for functions with block bodies because such functions may have complex control flow in the body, and the return type will be non-obvious to the reader (and sometimes even for the compiler).

So, the correct way to declare `compareTo(MyDate)` is to specify the return type of the function if it includes the block body:

```
operator fun compareTo(other: MyDate): Int {
    when {
        year != other.year -> return year - other.year
        month != other.month -> return month - other.month
        else -> return dayOfMonth - other.dayOfMonth
    }
}
```

This solves another error at the same time since the [comparison operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#comparison) is required to return an `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to [@Mibac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3533380/mibac)'s answer: You can make this a little bit shorter:

```
operator fun compareTo(other: MyDate) = when {
    year != other.year -> year - other.year
    month != other.month -> month - other.month
    else -> dayOfMonth - other.dayOfMonth
}
```